# Get two table column values into single column

Tags: mysql

I have two tables as

```
table1
------------
id_1 | name_1 | valu1
_____________________
1    | name1  | 3
2    | abc1   | 3
3    | xyz1   | 3

table2
________________

id_2 | name_2 | valu1
_______________________
1    | name2  | 3
2    | abc2   | 3
3    | xyz2   | 3
```

now I need a result table as

```
derived_name | d_valu1
__________________________
name1        | 3
abc1         | 3
xyz1         | 3
name2        | 3
abc2         | 3
xyz2         | 3
```

How can I get this table with MySQL queries. Please help

Comment: thanks for fast response their I have some restriction I don't want  to use union ,is there any other way

Comment: Why can't you use `UNION`? It is the natural way to do this (and is the type of problem that `UNION` is designed for). It's certainly not a `JOIN` problem. Another way would be to create a new, temporary table from `table1` and `table2` but that's very inefficient and what `UNION` helps to avoid (bypassing the step of temporary table creation).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a `UNION` as follows:

```
(SELECT name_1 as derived_name, valu1 as d_valu1 FROM table1)
UNION
(SELECT name_2 as derived_name, valu1 as d_valu1 FROM table2)
```